# How to use tornado to get the fragment stuff in a url?

Tags: url, web, tornado

When authorization with a sns website. My callback url is www.xxxxx.com/callback. The server redirect to this url add some stuff to this url like this
"http://www.xxxxx.com/callback#a=b&c=d". So I want to know how to get the stuff after #.

The request object is like this:

`HTTPRequest(
    protocal='http',
    headers={...}
)`

There are no information about fragment stuff in the url, and I don't know how to get it cause from the HTTPRequest object I can not see anything about it.

So I want to know how to obtain the original information about the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fragment, that is anything after and including the hash (`#`) in a URL is not sent to the server. You can access it via JavaScript in the browser. If you really need to access it on the server side, you can send it using an AJAX request.